# Не работает планировщик задач schedule

Tags: python, циклы, schedule

У меня есть скрипт, который выкладывает посты в вк, хочу чтобы он выкладывал их, каждый день в определенное время. Для теста, решил поставить выполнения скрипта скрипта через 5 секунд. Но почему то ничего не работает, запускаю скрипт, потом захожу в группу, через 10 секунд, куда должен был выложиться пост, там ничего нет. Потом выполняю скрипт без библиотеки `schedule`, все работает. Подскажите в чем проблема?

КОД:

```
import requests
import time
import schedule

test = '-63869928'
text = 'Test, Test, Test'
image = 'photo395296157_457250641'

global token
token = 'Мой токен'

def safe_file():
    a = requests.post('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post', data={
                                                             'owner_id': test,
                                                             "access_token": token,
                                                             'v': 5.122,
                                                             'message': text,
                                                             'attachments': image,
                                                             }).json()
    print(a)

def parser():
    print('\n', '  Начинается выгрузка постов', '\n', '  Пожалуйста подождите...')
    safe_file()
    print('  Готово!')

# parser()

job1 = schedule.every(5).seconds.do(parser)

for i in range(2):
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

schedule.cancel_job(job1)
```

Comment: Вы выполняете `schedule.run_pending()` всего два раза (набирается только две секунды - вот и не выполняется). Используйте `while True`  вместо `for i in range(2)`

Comment: Дак у меня будет, выкладывать каждые 5 секунд, а мне нужно чтобы скрипт выложил всего лишь один раз пост, а не бесконечное количество раз. Для этого я пишу в конце функцию, остановки скрипта: `schedule.cancel_job(job1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы используете цикл `for i in range(2)`, который вызовет `schedule.run_pending()` всего два раза. Следовательно `scheduler`, который ждёт 5 секунд никогда не выполнится.

Вот код для примера:

```
import time
import schedule

def function():
    print("Function complete!")


job = schedule.every(5).seconds.do(function)

for i in range(2):
    print(5 - i, "seconds left")
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

schedule.cancel_job(job)
print("Canceled")
```

Вывод:

> 5 seconds left 
> 4 seconds left 
> Canceled

---

Вы может использовать:

```
import time
import schedule

def function():
    print("Function complete!\n")


job = schedule.every(5).seconds.do(function)

i = 5
while True:    
    print(i, "seconds left")      
    if i == 0: i = 5
    i -= 1 
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Вывод:

> 5 seconds left 
> 4 seconds left 
> 3 seconds left 
> 2 seconds left 
> 1 seconds left 
> 0 seconds left 
> Function complete! 
>  
> 4 seconds left 
> 3 seconds left 
> 2 seconds left 
> 1 seconds left 
> 0 seconds left 
> Function complete!

---

Вы сказали:

> хочу чтобы он выкладывал их, **каждый день** в определенное время

следовательно вам не нужен:

```
schedule.cancel_job(job)
```

Достаточно настроить задержку или использовать:

```
schedule.every().day.at("time").do(job)
```

---

Но если вам всё же нужно отменять задачу, можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
i = 5
canceled = False
while True:    
    print(i, "seconds left")      
    if i == 0: i = 5
    if canceled:
        schedule.cancel_job(job)
        break
    i -= 1 
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Когда `canceled` станет равен `True` - `scheduler` остановится.